# Logout All sessions for an account in express-session, postgresql (connect-pg-simple)

Tags: javascript, postgresql, authentication, passport.js, express-session

I was wondering how one would create a route to logout **all** sessions (**not just the current one**) for a user when using `express-session` and `connect-pg-simple` as a session store.

I have the sessions table name set as user_sessions and have previously been able to achieve this using the mysql store on a previous project, which went something like this;

```
const db = require("../db/connection");

exports.logoutAllDevices = async (user_id) => {
// req.logout(); -- I called this in the controller just before, left it here to show its been called
let logoutAllQuery = 'DELETE FROM user_sessions WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(`data`, "$.passport.user") = $1;';
await db.query(logoutAllQuery, [user_id]);
return;
};
```

which i found before and the idea was to destroy all sessions related to that user as well as calling the `req.logout()` function.

However, I can't get any solution to work with this postgres store. Help is appreciated.